# Python Frozen Executable Files are not Working on Some Computers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, cx-freeze

My frozen Python files are working on my computer correctly.  I froze them with `cx_freeze`, but on some computers they do not work.  For example in Windows 7, it always needs DLL files, it says they are missing.  It is usually about `api-ms-win` DLL files.

In Windows 10, it shows this error:

[image: Windows 10 Error]

But on my computer, it works correctly. How is this possible, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your computer has the DLLs

Comment: @StephenRauch can i learn, which dll are required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many potential problems, but the most common with Python 3.5+ and Windows 10 seems to be missing `api-ms-win` dlls.

**To help my Python freeze program to find required DLLs:**

Here is one set of notes from the `pyinstaller` issue tracker:

> Add the directory of the required dlls to system Path. My application uses PyQt5 which is dependent on api-ms-win dlls.
>
> For PyQt5 add this directory:

```
%WHERE EVER YOU INSTALLED PYTHON%\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin
```

> For api-ms-win dlls you need Visual Studio 2015 OR Windows SDK (download here):
> Directory if you have Visual Studio: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64
> Directory if you have Windows SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x64

After you add the required paths, pyinstaller can find the files.

([SOURCE](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1566#issuecomment-269741477))

**But what DLL's are missing?**

Too help find any missing DLLs, you can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find all of the DLL's that your program needs.

**Should I use Pyinstaller instead?**

It is often worth trying some of the other freeze utils if the one you are using is not cooperating.

Comment: Actually i froze with cx_freeze, do you suggest pyinstaller?

Comment: Your tags mentioned `cx-freeze`, so I was aware that it is what you used. I use `pyinstaller`, and am an occasional contributer to same, so I follow their issue tracker.  So I was aware that the notes I cited were available their.  That is the only reason I mentioned `pyinstaller`. So yes, I would suggest trying `pyinstaller`, but as far as I know, they both suffer from this issue.

Comment: i froze with pyinstaller and it works now. thank you.